# How to make ACL allow if user is owner of the resource?

Tags: php, permissions, roles, acl

Looking at Zend ACL and other similar ACL's, it seems to, and I may be wrong here, to only allow you to allow/deny an action by a role on a resource.

But what if say for example that you have users who are editors and they are allowed to "edit" "posts" but what if you only wanted to allow them to edit "posts" owned by the user?

How is this situation handled in the real world? I would prefer to avoid something like...

```
if ($acl->allowed($role, $action, $resource) and $resource->user_id == $user_id) { ... }
```

Comment: did you try with assertions? http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.advanced.html